# search specifice file with path from a particular directory and its sub directory

Tags: php

I have to find live.php and its path within a directory suppose module and its all sub directories such as user, blog  and etc. Search also if sub directory blog contains further sub directories.

I am using a long code to do this job. Any other better and short method.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look at PHP `glob` http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Example : Search `dir/module` and sub directory  for `live.php` or anything that ends with `live.php`

```
glob_recursive('dir/module/*live.php');
```

Function used : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#106595

```
if ( ! function_exists('glob_recursive'))
{
    function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0)
    {
        $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
        foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
        {
            $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
        }
        return $files;
    }
}
```